# Display an image upload with Wagtail in a react frontend

Tags: reactjs, wagtail

I have upload some images with wagtail but i can't display them in react, i have a blank space with the alternative text.

in fact, at the place of the image I have an id but i want the url to display the image.

How can i display image from wagtail to react ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are fetching images from API.
Add this class in your model

```
class APIRichTextSerializer(fields.CharField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        return expand_db_html(representation)
```

Then use this as serializer to your API field,

```
APIField("content", serializer=APIRichTextSerializer()),
```

it will return the API data as a normal API response.

Comment: what is this expand_db_html?

Comment: it will allow you to expand your HTML from Django-secured HTML format to normal HTML format, which will help to capture inside stories photos easily.

Comment: how can i import it?

Comment: Please share your API response to the question.